# Good example of Quantity or Money class

Tags: .net, currency

Does someone know of a good .NET implementation of Quantity (with Unit of Measure) or Money (with Currency) classess/patterns in .NET ?

Comment: Are you looking for specific implementations or models of the patterns? I believe both are patterns in Martin Fowler's books.

Comment: I am looking for implementation.

Comment: You can see Quantity writed by Martin Fowler

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This Money class](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/MoneyTypeForCLR.aspx) is terrific, and the article discusses why the developer made the decisions he did (compared to several other implementations).

Comment: The answer linked to is most of all **large** and overkill for an application without the specific needs that that implementation was built for. Don't take it as a silver bullet.